# Statement X in SAS

Tags: sharepoint, sas, export, sas-macro

I'm trying to export a file to sharepoint with SAS, when I test it with cmd It works, but when I test it with sas, I have an error.

```
X copy 'C:\Users\XX.XX\Desktop\Stage\Mantis\testExport\qsf.txt \\XX.sharepoint.com\Documents%20partages\qsf.txt';
```

Error :

```
1                                                          Le Système SAS                              17:01 Wednesday, May 22, 2019

1          ;*';*";*/;quit;run;
2          OPTIONS PAGENO=MIN;
3          %LET _CLIENTTASKLABEL='Programme (2)';
4          %LET _CLIENTPROJECTPATH='C:\Users\XXX.XXX\Desktop\Stage\Mantis\testExport\Projet.egp';
5          %LET _CLIENTPROJECTNAME='Projet.egp';
6          %LET _SASPROGRAMFILE=;
7          
8          ODS _ALL_ CLOSE;
9          OPTIONS DEV=ACTIVEX;
10         GOPTIONS XPIXELS=0 YPIXELS=0;
11         FILENAME EGSR TEMP;
12         ODS tagsets.sasreport13(ID=EGSR) FILE=EGSR
13             STYLE=HtmlBlue
14             STYLESHEET=(URL="file:///D:/SAS/SASEnterpriseGuide/7.1/Styles/HtmlBlue.css")
15             NOGTITLE
16             NOGFOOTNOTE
17             GPATH=&sasworklocation
18             ENCODING=UTF8
19             options(rolap="on")
20         ;
NOTE: Writing TAGSETS.SASREPORT13(EGSR) Body file: EGSR
21         
22         GOPTIONS ACCESSIBLE;
The specified file is not found.
23         data _null_;
24         X 'copy C:\Users\XXX.XXX\Desktop\Stage\Mantis\testExport\qsf.txt
24       ! \\XXX.sharepoint.com\Documents%20partages\qsf.txt';
25         run;
```

So I don't understand why It doesn't find the file ...

Comment: don't know sharepoint but `%20` is ok in the file path ?

Answer (score 0):

when you say you tested it with cmd you mean in Unix? 
If yes, your SAS may not be configured to export files to sharepoint. My SAS is setup in a way to not export files to desktop.
If no, let's debug more.

Comment: No, with windows